# HTML Form is converting spaces to + instead of %20 when building url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying set up a single address input field and have that address append to the end of the url. The form below works fine if I use a single word for the address, like a really unique street name.

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="http://gisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us/Html5Viewer_2_0/Index.html" target="_blank">
<div>
    <label for="searchText">Search:</label>
    <input id="configBase" type="hidden" value="http://gisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us/Geocortex/Essentials/REST/sites/BOS_APP/viewers/SLO_County_BOS/virtualdirectory/Resources/Config/Default" name="configBase" />
    <input id="run" type="hidden" value="GeocodingWorkflow" name="run" />
    <input id="searchText" type="text" name="Address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</div>
```

However, if I type in "123 Main Street", I get:

`http://gisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us/Html5Viewer_2_0/Index.html?configBase=http%3A%2F%2Fgisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us%2FGeocortex%2FEssentials%2FREST%2Fsites%2FBOS_APP%2Fviewers%2FSLO_County_BOS%2Fvirtualdirectory%2FResources%2FConfig%2FDefault&run=GeocodingWorkflow&Address=123+Main+Street`

which loads but does not zoom into the address, instead of:

`http://gisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us/Html5Viewer_2_0/Index.html?configBase=http%3A%2F%2Fgisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us%2FGeocortex%2FEssentials%2FREST%2Fsites%2FBOS_APP%2Fviewers%2FSLO_County_BOS%2Fvirtualdirectory%2FResources%2FConfig%2FDefault&run=GeocodingWorkflow&Address=123%20Main%20Street`

which does zoom in if entered manually into the address bar.

Is there an HTML way to convert the spaces to %20's instead of +'s? If not, is there a Javascript solution? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So, after more research, I built this and it seems to work:

```
<form onsubmit="buildurl()" name="AddressLookup">
    <input id="searchText" type="text" name="searchText" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildurl() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById("searchText");
        window.open("http://gisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us/Html5Viewer_2_0/Index.html?configBase=http%3A%2F%2Fgisdev2.wings.co.slo.ca.us%2FGeocortex%2FEssentials%2FREST%2Fsites%2FBOS_APP%2Fviewers%2FSLO_County_BOS%2Fvirtualdirectory%2FResources%2FConfig%2FDefault&run=GeocodingWorkflow&Address=" + searchText.value);
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone have anything to add? fix? Much appreciated.

Comment: The question should be why the site doesn't handle `+` the same as `%20` in the URL. You should first find out what the problem is with that, before you try to build your way around the problem.

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3) might suit.

Comment: That's how forms are encoded by default, it's based on a very early version of the general URI percent-encoding rules, where spaces are replaced by plus signs, and other than using javascript to create the URL there's no way around if. As noted by @Guffa, the server should handle a URL like that, as it's how URL's generally will look from a form submit.

Comment: @Guffa - I don't own or manage that product, and therefore cannot investigate that. My requirement is to be able to pass the correct url to the geocortex application.

Comment: @adeneo Using Javascript would be fine if you could provide an example that would be much appreciated.